# Добавить новое вычисляемое поле. Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

уважаемые программисты.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, в моем приложении есть таблица и я хотел сделать новое вычисляемое поле в самом низу приложения через лейбл в формате: "СУмма денег на балансе: ***"
*** - Данные из колонки Total.
ПРоще говоря нужно написать код который посчитает всю сумму и выведет ее в Лейбл.
Прикрепляю код.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3


class Main(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, root):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_main()
    self.db = db
    self.view_records()



def init_main(self):
    toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
    toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

    self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='add.gif')
    btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Добавить позицию', command=self.open_dialog, 
    bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0,
                                compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
    btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.update_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='update.gif')
    btn_edit_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Редактировать', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, 
    image=self.update_img,
                                compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_update_dialog)
    btn_edit_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.delete_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='delete.gif')
    btn_delete = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Удалить позицию', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, 
    image=self.delete_img,
                           compound=tk.TOP, command=self.delete_records)
    btn_delete.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.search_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='search.gif')
    btn_search = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Поиск', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, image=self.search_img,
                           compound=tk.TOP, command=self.open_search_dialog)
    btn_search.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.refresh_img = tk.PhotoImage(file='refresh.gif')
    btn_refresh = tk.Button(toolbar, text='Обновить', bg='#d7d8e0', bd=0, 
    image=self.refresh_img,
                            compound=tk.TOP, command=self.view_records)
    btn_refresh.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=('ID', 'description', 'costs', 'total'), height=15, 
    show='headings')

    self.tree.column('ID', width=30, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('description', width=365, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('costs', width=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
    self.tree.column('total', width=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)

    self.tree.heading('ID', text='ID')
    self.tree.heading('description', text='Наименование')
    self.tree.heading('costs', text='Статья дохода/расхода')
    self.tree.heading('total', text='Сумма')

    self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.tree.yview)
    scroll.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.Y)
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
    

    def records(self, description, costs, total):
    self.db.insert_data(description, costs, total)
    self.view_records()

    def update_record(self, description, costs, total):
    self.db.c.execute('''UPDATE finance SET description=?, costs=?, total=? WHERE ID=?''',
                      (description, costs, total, self.tree.set(self.tree.selection()[0], 
     '#1')))
    self.db.conn.commit()
    self.view_records()

    def view_records(self):
    self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM finance''')
    [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
    [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]

    def delete_records(self):
    for selection_item in self.tree.selection():
        self.db.c.execute('''DELETE FROM finance WHERE id=?''', (self.tree.set(selection_item, '#1'),))
    self.db.conn.commit()
    self.view_records()

def search_records(self, description):
    description = ('%' + description + '%',)
    self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM finance WHERE description LIKE ?''', description)
    [self.tree.delete(i) for i in self.tree.get_children()]
    [self.tree.insert('', 'end', values=row) for row in self.db.c.fetchall()]

def open_dialog(self):
    Child()

def open_update_dialog(self):
    Update()

def open_search_dialog(self):
    Search()


class Child(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(root)
    self.init_child()
    self.view = app

def Clear(self):
    self.entry_description.delete(0, "end")
    self.entry_money.delete(0, "end")


def init_child(self):
    self.title('Добавить доходы/расходы')
    self.geometry('400x220+400+300')
    self.resizable(False, False)

    label_description = tk.Label(self, text='Наименование:')
    label_description.place(x=50, y=50)
    label_select = tk.Label(self, text='Статья дохода/расхода:')
    label_select.place(x=50, y=80)
    label_sum = tk.Label(self, text='Сумма:')
    label_sum.place(x=50, y=110)

    def validate(new_value):  # +++
        return new_value == "" or new_value.isnumeric()
    vcmd = (root.register(validate), '%P')

    self.entry_description = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.entry_description.place(x=200, y=50)

    self.entry_money = ttk.Entry(self, validate='key', validatecommand=vcmd)
    self.entry_money.place(x=200, y=110)

    self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self, values=[u'Доход', u'Расход'])
    self.combobox.current(0)
    self.combobox.place(x=200, y=80)

    btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
    btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=170)

    self.btn_ok = ttk.Button(self, text='Добавить')
    self.btn_ok.place(x=220, y=170)
    self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.records(self.entry_description.get(),
                                                                   self.combobox.get(),
                                                                   self.entry_money.get()))

    self.btn_ok = ttk.Button(self, text='Очистить')
    self.btn_ok.place(x=120, y=170)
    self.btn_ok.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.Clear())


    self.grab_set()
    self.focus_set()



class Update(Child):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_edit()
    self.view = app
    self.db = db
    self.default_data()

def init_edit(self):
    self.title('Редактировать позицию')
    btn_edit = ttk.Button(self, text='Редактировать')
    btn_edit.place(x=205, y=170)
    btn_edit.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.view.update_record(self.entry_description.get(),
                                                                      self.combobox.get(),
                                                                      self.entry_money.get()))

    self.btn_ok.destroy()

def default_data(self):
    self.db.c.execute('''SELECT * FROM finance WHERE id=?''',
                      (self.view.tree.set(self.view.tree.selection()[0], '#1'),))
    row = self.db.c.fetchone()
    self.entry_description.insert(0, row[1])
    if row[2] != 'Доход':
        self.combobox.current(1)
    self.entry_money.insert(0, row[3])


class Search(tk.Toplevel):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_search()
    self.view = app

def init_search(self):
    self.title('Поиск')
    self.geometry('300x100+400+300')
    self.resizable(False, False)

    label_search = tk.Label(self, text='Поиск')
    label_search.place(x=50, y=20)

    self.entry_search = ttk.Entry(self)
    self.entry_search.place(x=105, y=20, width=150)

    btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text='Закрыть', command=self.destroy)
    btn_cancel.place(x=185, y=50)

    btn_search = ttk.Button(self, text='Поиск')
    btn_search.place(x=105, y=50)
    btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: 
    self.view.search_records(self.entry_search.get()))
    btn_search.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: self.destroy(), add='+')


    class DB:
    def __init__(self):
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect('finance.db')
    self.c = self.conn.cursor()
    self.c.execute(
        '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS finance (id integer primary key, description text, costs text, total real)''')
    self.conn.commit()

def insert_data(self, description, costs, total):
    self.c.execute('''INSERT INTO finance(description, costs, total) VALUES (?, ?, ?)''',
                   (description, costs, total))
    self.conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
root = tk.Tk()
db = DB()
app = Main(root)
app.pack()
root.title("Управление финансами")
root.geometry("665x450+300+200")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А что случилось-то с написанием этой части кода? Что именно не работает?

Comment: Не понимаю как именно сделать поле вычисляемым что бы из столбца сумма все посчиталось и занеслосб в лейбл

Comment: Кто пробовал сделать такое?

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйсте! Попробуйте, вот пример правильного ответа:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def counting(e):
    entry1Text = entry1.get()
    entry2Text = entry2.get()
    if entry1Text.isdigit() and entry2Text.isdigit(): # во избежание ошибок конвертации пустоты, или букв в цифры
        sum = str(int(entry1Text) + int(entry2Text))
        label.config(text=sum)
    else:
        label.config(text="0")

entry1 = Entry()
entry1.bind("<KeyRelease>", counting)
entry1.pack()

entry2 = Entry()
entry2.bind("<KeyRelease>", counting)
entry2.pack()

label = Label(text="0")
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Просто все свои Entry забиндите на отжатие любой клавиши, и в функции текст лейбы меняйте на сумму всех Entry.